# SVN Merge One file from revision to another branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to Merge one file from a specific revision number (Which may have multiple files) to a particular Branch.

For e.g -

Branch 1 contains revision number 156 with 5 committed files (Or any). I want to merge 1 (Or specific) file to Branch 2.

Is there any possible way to achieve this ?

Comment: I checked it but couldn't able to locate. That's why I asked it here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> `svn merge SOURCE[@REV] [TARGET_WCPATH]`
>
> ... If you want to merge only a subtree, then the subtree path must be
>   included in both SOURCE and TARGET_WCPATH